# Windows 8 to Ubuntu, new Acer Aspire V3-772G

Tags: system-installation, uefi, partitioning

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my new [Acer Aspire V3-772G](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-V3-772G-747A321-Notebook.93916.0.html). Unfortunantly, when I boot from my bootable USB drive with `nomodeset` it doesn't load the graphical interface, but when I click ctrl+alt+1 I'll get a commandline. This isn't a big problem, because the installer boots and works (good?). Now, I'm currently dealing with the following:

My current disk-layout is, in the same order (displayed in the Windows diskmanager):

SSD 1 (256GB) partitions:

- 400 MB recovery partition
- 300 MB EFI system partition
- 219.66 GB C:/ (windows)
- 18.01 GB recovery partition

HDD 1 (1TB) partitions:

- 931.51GB D:/ (windows)

I would like to move my recovery partitions to the 1TB HDD and fully wipe my SSD.. This because I would like to be able to recover my notebook back to Windows, in case something is wrong in the hardware or so. Also, what's the EFI partition doing there? Are I'm able to remove it for Ubuntu? And will I'm be able to recover Windows without this partition?

NOTE: I've also tried to create a new partition of ~20GB on the HDD (and shrink the D partition) and use the Create recovery station utility in Windows, but this doesn't recognize the extra partition in any way.. (With/without disk number (like C/D in Windows)

I hope you can give me some answers. I really would like to install Ubuntu on my new notebook..

Thanks

More details:

- Fast boot off
- Secure boot off
- UEFI on

Comment: The UEFI needs the EFI partition to work. You shouldn't remove it. The computer won't boot if you do. The matter of moving the recovery partition or creating a new one in another drive relates to Windows and has nothing to do with Ubuntu. That is off-topic here. One solution may be to shrink the C:/ and leave the space unallocated using Windows. Ubuntu (side-by-side) installation **should** recognize the free space and create the two partitions it needs there.

Comment: Do you have much data on the 1 TB HDD?